# How to style angular-google-line-chart to have two styles for the same line?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I would like to have a Line Chart using angular-google-chart to show some statistics and also future projection. I want my projection to be dashed lines. Below is my sample code. Currently, my line chart will show the same color for the statistics and future projection. I want it to be different color or maybe dashed for the future projection.

**HTML**

```
<div google-chart chart="stat"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.stat = {
          "type": "LineChart",
          "displayed": false,
          "data": {
            "cols": [
              {
                "id": "date",
                "label": "Date",
                "type": "string",
              },
              {
                "id": "sales-id",
                "label": "Sales",
                "type": "number",
              },
            ],
            "rows": [
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "20 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 19,
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "21 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 17,
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "22 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 18,
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "23 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 18,
                  }
                ]
              },
              //FUTURE PROJECTION
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "24 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 17,
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "c": [
                  {
                    "v": "25 Nov"
                  },
                  {
                    "v": 15,
                  }
                ]
              },
            ]
          },
          "options": {
            "isStacked": "true",
            "fill": 20,
            "displayExactValues": true,
            "legend": {"position":'none'},
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve the desired results by utilizing [column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles):

> A column role describes the purpose of the data in that column: for
>   example, a column might hold data describing tooltip text, data point
>   annotations, or uncertainty indicators.

So, let's introduce a *style role* column:

```
 {
       "type": "string",
       "role": "style",
       "p": { "role": "style" }
 }
```

And then, specify line style:

```
 { "v": "line { stroke-color: green }" }
```

The following modified example demonstrates how to style line segments in different colors:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart']);

app.controller('chartCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.stat = {
        "type": "LineChart",
        "displayed": false,
        "data": {
            "cols": [
              {
                  "id": "date",
                  "label": "Date",
                  "type": "string",
              },
              {
                  "id": "sales-id",
                  "label": "Sales",
                  "type": "number",
              },
              {
                  "type": "string",
                  "role": "style",
                  "p": { "role": "style" }
              }
            ],
            "rows": [
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "20 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 19,
                    },
                    { "v": null }

                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "21 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 17,
                    },
                    { "v": null }

                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "22 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 18,
                    },
                    { "v": null }

                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "23 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 18,
                    },
                    { "v": null }

                  ]
              },
              //FUTURE PROJECTION
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "24 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 17,
                    },
                    { "v": "line { stroke-color: green }" }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "25 Nov"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 15,
                    },
                    { "v": "line { stroke-color: green }" }
                  ]
              },
            ]
        },
        "options": {
            "isStacked": "true",
            "fill": 20,
            "displayExactValues": true,
            "legend": { "position": 'none' },
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="chartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="stat"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/gqgL6wf3/)

Comment: well, what if I have more than one line? How could I have style for each of them? I think duplicating it is enough. `"cols": [{"id": "date","label": "Date","type": "string"},{"id": "sales-id","label": "Sales","type": "number"},{"id": "expenses-id","label": "Expense","type": "number"},{"type": "string","role": "style","p": { "role": "style" },{"type": "string","role": "style","p": { "role": "style" }}`

Comment: That's right, we need to define additional style column(s)